# ASP.NET page calls Java Applet and fields lost focus

Tags: java, javascript, asp.net, applet

I have a asp.Net application that make calls to a java applet. 
Requests via javascript work as expected without problems. however 
there is a mechanism that searches the time intervals in the applet. 
(using setInterval) 
And when this mechanism is triggered the page "loses" focus.

For example, if I'm with the focus on a text field, and the call occurs, the focus leaves the field.

I tried to go the other way, the applet calling the page, but the result was the same.

I also tried putting this control inside an UpdatePanel, to try to isolate the callback but it still fails.

Also tried putting inside an iframe, but it still fails.

Here is the code that makes the request

```js
function initTimerDevices() {
    setInterval(getDeviceStatus, 5000);
}

function getDeviceStatus(name) {
    document.applet.getDeviceStatus("ASDF");            
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    initTimerDevices();
});
```

And here is the ASP

```asp
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <applet name="Myapplet" code=com.xpto.applet.class 
             archive="applet.jar"
             width="0.5" height="0.5">
         </applet>    
         <ul id="ulDevices">                    
         </ul>         
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Is there any way to make the call to the applet asynchronously? Or other form that causes this loss of focus does not exist.

Comment: *"and here is the html"*  No that is ASP.  HTML is what ends up in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

One problem here is in the use of the [`ready()`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) function which:

> ..will only run once the page **Document Object Model (DOM) is ready** for JavaScript code to execute.

That will probably be some time **before:**

1. The JVM is loaded.
2. The applet Jars or classes are loaded.
3. The applet itself has gone through the `init()` and `start()` methods.

Better to initiate this code from within the applet.